# Bootstrap popover isn't placed correctly even with container: 'body' set

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a button in a table which should toggle a popover. I have set the `data-container="body"` as well as I have tried it with the javascript version.

My popover looks like this: (I have clicked the first button)

[image]

My button code is here:

```
<button id="testsettracesBtn1" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

And here my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#testsettracesBtn1").popover({ container: 'body'});
</script>
```

How can i achieve it to place my popover right? (And yes I have the newest bootstrap version.)

Comment: Try adding a http://jsfiddle.net/ to your question. 
And define right. Is it not centered right middle enough?
Or is it currently on top?

Comment: I created a JsFiddle, but it won't reproduce on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x58uM/1/. With right i mean: right of the button and vertically centered on the button.

Comment: Well if the same code works in jsfiddle but not in your file, the problem is most likely outside of the code. JS include order maybe? Or your CSS could throw the styles off.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I found my problem. It's a select within a span. I used this to color specific statuses. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/x58uM/2/. Do i have to think about a different "coloring" method or can I continue using the badge?

Comment: Thats what a div is for ;)

Comment: Thank you. I replaced it with a div. I thought it was the span, but it wasn't after minutes of Firebugging i found out, that the positioning of the popover is allergic to selects in a table... If i remove all of them, the popover is placed correct. I have many controls, because it should be editable. Do you have any ideas now?

Comment: I would say create a new well formulated question and put an answer in this one so people searching can see that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This strange behaviour is caused because of many `select` elements in within my table. I don't know why? I just changed the width of the popover to `max-width`, after the button is being clicked. With the correct width also the arrow is positioned right:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("[id^=kommentareBtn-]").popover({ container: 'body', placement: 'bottom', html: true });

    //this fixed my problem...
    $("[id^=kommentareBtn-]").click(function() {
      $(".popover").css("width", "276px");
    });
});
```

Comment: Same issue here: Popovers are not placed correctly, but when I pre-assign the `width` and `height` of them they are placed correctly.

Comment: My problem was that I was setting the popover title with jQuery programmatically after the creation of the popover. Doing this a bit earlier fixed the issue.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, but the source of the bug was that my Bootstrap framework was outdated. I upgraded to 2.3.2 and the `container: 'body'` attribute started working.

It caused me quite a headache... until I found out the problem was not in my own code!

Comment: This solved it for me. Our version was 2.2.2, so i just copied tooltip code from 2.3.2 and now content:"body" works.